# How to make (if it's possible) "`" character on windows without ALT + 96?

Tags: windows, keyboard, hotkeys

I'm using an Italian keyboard so notice that I don't have that char on the keyboard by default.

However, I'm programming and I need that char quite often. I know only the alt + 96 technique but it's quite slow.

I would like to know if there is a combination to make that char like ctrl + alt + shift + "'" to make it.

Or I would like to know if that combination simply doesn't exist.

Thanks a lot for answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7: Mapping a key to something that is not on the keyboard](http://superuser.com/questions/385358/windows-7-mapping-a-key-to-something-that-is-not-on-the-keyboard)

Comment: Nope, I don't want to map anything, I would like to know if it's already mapped or not and if yes which is the key combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) (MSKLC) allows you to create custom layouts (starting form scratch or modifying an existing one) and to validate such a layout.

The validation process will warn you if the same character is assigned to two different keys, so you can use it to find out if the backtick is lurking somewhere.

Comment: Nice! I changed my answer, that's really nice!

Answer (score 1):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is your friend

Comment: Yea but I'm not asking how to make it through a program, I'm asking if it's already mapped in some way. I imagine no by the way.

Answer (score 0):

While I understand that there isn't an **already mapped** hotkey to make that character, the uSlackr suggestion is maybe the best way to obtain such a thing. I upvoted him but that is not directly the answer to what I'm asking.

Comment: So you selected your own non-answer?  Seems like an odd approach.  Perhaps you should leave it unanswered for now.

Comment: Definitely not true. I waited 1 month for an answer and if anyone answered this it means that actually Windows 7 doesn't have such an hotkey, I think I waited enough time. That being said your answer doesn't answer mine, while in my answer is written *there isn't an already mapped hotkey* which answers directly to the question. Also your answer even if it is a good suggestion is incomplete, techie007 pointed me in the exact direction while you only suggested a software. That being said, stackoverflow suggest to use this approach for answers-collage and unanswered questions.